# How to use document.querySelector to search for a pattern match and fill value

Tags: javascript

I have an element in an webpage

> id="1253~~0~0~506~13501157_txtValue"

I want to search all element matches beginning with this value **1253** and it should be filled up the value **test**

For this I am using this following code but it isnt working

```
document.querySelector('[id^ ='1253']').value = test
```

Please guide me as to where I am going wrong
Thanks in advance.
-Vicky.

Comment: Also, `querySelector` will only match the first element and not all the elements as you wanted. You need to use `querySelectorAll` and loop through each element from the collection to set the `value`

Answer (score 2):

Your selector is good but you should either use double quotes (`"`) and single quotes (`'`) or escape your inner single quotes.

Also, if `test` is not a variable you should surround it with quotes : `"test"`.

As pointed out by [@adiga](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3082296/adiga), if you want to match all elements whose `id` begins with `"1253"`, you should use [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and [loop through the results](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/loop-queryselectorall-matches/).

```js
document.querySelector("[id^='1253']").value = "test";
//the following line is equivalent
//document.querySelector('[id^=\'1253\']').value = "test";
```

```html
<input type="text" id="1253~~0~0~506~13501157_txtValue" />
```

Comment: You're right about the selector, but @adiga's comment is also important - `querySelector()` only matches the first element, while the OP is looking for all matches, and thus should use `querySelectorAll()` and loop over the result.

Comment: @Tom, Thank your for answering but the code didnt work. I have providedthe link of my webpage here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rwKENh6Vgx04iewegijURpE8MeOpp0YC/view?usp=sharing
Please guide me to use the correct JS code as the code which you had sent had not worked